# output is not matching with expected output in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

My question is: Create Stored procedure which takes as input different filters such as price range,
category, product rating, seller rating, out of stock and displays the list of products with
all the details after applying filters.

And i have written following code in pl/sql oracle

```
create or replace procedure filter_query(l in number,r in number,catg in varchar,prat in float,srat in float,oos in number)
as 
begin
  if(oos=1)
  then
  declare
  pname product.p_name%type;
  cursor ptr is
  select p_name from product where ((amount between l and r) and  (ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ=catg)) and (rating=prat) and (sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating=srat)) and (qt_rem=0)) ;
  begin
    open ptr;
    loop
    fetch ptr into pname;
    exit when ptr%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(pname);
    end loop;
    close ptr;
  end;
  if(oos=0)
  then
  declare
  pname product.p_name%type;
  cursor ptr is
  select p_name from product where ((amount between l and r) and  (ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ=catg)) and (rating=prat) and (sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating=srat)) and (qt_rem>0)) ;
  begin
    open ptr;
    loop
    fetch ptr into pname;
    exit when ptr%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(pname);
    end loop;
    close ptr;
  end;
  end if;
  end if;
end;
/
```

And my main script is:

```
declare 
sname varchar(20);
begin
 filter_query(500,1000,'Home Decor',3.6,3.3,0);
end;
/
```

Product table
[image: Product table]

Seller table
[image: Seller table]

Category Table
[image: Category Table]

The output should be 'White Lamp' as its amount is between 500 to 1000 and rating=3.6 and seller rating '5S' is also 3.3 and category is 'House Decor'. But It is showing nothing why? Please help. I am not able to figure out mistake

Comment: Don't post images of tables, post DDL and DML as **text**.

Comment: Please reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table CATEGORY (
  CT_ID  char(2)
 ,CATEG  varchar2(20)
)
/
insert into CATEGORY values ('2C','Footwear')
/
insert into CATEGORY values ('1C','Books')
/
insert into CATEGORY values ('3C','Home Decor')
/
insert into CATEGORY values ('4C','Accessories')
/
create table SELLER (
  SL_ID    char(2)
 ,SL_NAME  char(5)
 ,RATING   number(2, 1)
)
/
insert into SELLER values ('2S','Priya', 2.5)
/
insert into SELLER values ('4S','Vicky', 4.7)
/
insert into SELLER values ('5S','Sneha', 3.3)
/
insert into SELLER values ('1S','Abhay', 3.5)
/
create table PRODUCT (
  P_ID    char(2)
 ,P_NAME  varchar2(35)
 ,AMOUNT  number(4)
 ,QT_REM  number(1)
 ,CT_ID   char(2)
 ,SL_ID   char(2)
 ,RATING  number(2, 1)
)
/
insert into PRODUCT
values ('1P'
       ,'The programming language of oracle'
       ,350
       ,4
       ,'1C'
       ,'1S'
       ,3.5)
/
insert into PRODUCT
values ('2P'
       ,'Nike White shoes'
       ,7000
       ,2
       ,'2C'
       ,'3S'
       ,3.25)
/
insert into PRODUCT
values ('3P'
       ,'White Lamp'
       ,800
       ,3
       ,'3C'
       ,'5S'
       ,3.6)
/
create or replace procedure FILTER_QUERY(l in number
                                        ,r in number
                                        ,catg in varchar
                                        ,prat in float
                                        ,srat in float
                                        ,oos in number)
as
  pname product.p_name%type;
  cursor ptr is
    select p_name
      from product
     where amount between l and r
       and ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ=catg)
       and rating=prat
       and sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating=srat)
       and qt_rem=0;
  cursor ptr2 is
    select p_name
      from product
     where amount between l and r
       and ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ=catg)
       and rating=prat
       and sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating=srat)
       and qt_rem>0;
begin
  if oos=1 then
    open ptr;
    loop
      fetch ptr into pname;
      exit when ptr%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(pname);
    end loop;
    close ptr;
  elsif oos=0 then
    open ptr2;
    loop
      fetch ptr2 into pname;
      exit when ptr2%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(pname);
    end loop;
    close ptr2;
  end if;
end;
/
set serveroutput on
declare
  sname varchar2(35);
begin
  filter_query(500,1000,'Home Decor',3.6,3.3,0);
end;
/
White Lamp

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: @SITANSHUYADAV - but do you _understand why_ the answer is working and your's wasn't?  ;What have you _learned_ from this?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is the opening `if(oos=1)` encloses the whole procedure, so if `oos` is anything other than `1` then processing ends. This would be clearer if you formatted your code (it's one reason why we do that in programming), or if you run it through the debugger. It's also complicated by some unnecessary `begin`/`end` blocks and repetition, which make it harder to see the structure (or to maintain it in the future). A fixed version would be:

```
create or replace procedure filter_query
    ( l    in number
    , r    in number
    , catg in varchar2
    , prat in float
    , srat in float
    , oos  in number )
as
    pname product.p_name%type;
begin
    if oos = 1 then
        declare
            cursor ptr is
                select p_name
                from   product
                where  amount between l and r
                and    ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ = catg)
                and    rating = prat
                and    sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating = srat)
                and    qt_rem = 0;
        begin
            open ptr;
            loop
                fetch ptr into pname;
                exit when ptr%notfound;
                dbms_output.put_line(pname);
            end loop;
            close ptr;
        end;

    elsif oos = 0 then
        declare
            cursor ptr is
                select p_name
                from   product
                where  amount between l and r
                and    ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ = catg)
                and    rating = prat
                and    sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating = srat)
                and    qt_rem > 0;
        begin
            open ptr;
            loop
                fetch ptr into pname;
                exit when ptr%notfound;
                dbms_output.put_line(pname);
            end loop;
            close ptr;
        end;
    end if;
end filter_query;
```

However, the two blocks are identical except for the final condition, so you could simplify it by having one block that picks one of two cursors:

```
create or replace procedure filter_query
    ( l    in number
    , r    in number
    , catg in varchar2
    , prat in float
    , srat in float
    , oos  in number )
as
    pname product.p_name%type;
    ptr sys_refcursor;
begin
    if oos = 1 then
        open ptr for
            select p_name
            from   product
            where  amount between l and r
            and    ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ = catg)
            and    rating = prat
            and    sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating = srat)
            and    qt_rem = 0;

    elsif oos = 0 then
        open ptr for
            select p_name
            from   product
            where  amount between l and r
            and    ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ = catg)
            and    rating = prat
            and    sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating = srat)
            and    qt_rem > 0;
    end if;

    loop
        fetch ptr into pname;
        exit when ptr%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(pname);
    end loop;

    close ptr;

end filter_query;
```

Or, have one cursor and apply the filter logic in SQL:

```
create or replace procedure filter_query
    ( l    in number
    , r    in number
    , catg in varchar2
    , prat in float
    , srat in float
    , oos  in number )
as
begin
    for prod in (
        select p_name
        from   product
        where  amount between l and r
        and    ct_id in (select ct_id from category where categ = catg)
        and    rating = prat
        and    sl_id in (select sl_id from seller where rating = srat)
        and    (    ( oos = 1 and qt_rem = 0 )
                or  ( oos = 0 and qt_rem > 0 ) )
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(prod.p_name);
    end loop;
end filter_query;
```